# Memory corruption in Swift with pointers

Tags: c, swift

I have some code similar to the following:

```swift
/*
c struct def:
typedef struct {
   uint8_t data[3];
} StructInC;
c function:
void someCFunction(StructInC const * structPointer);
*/
// imported C struct type
struct StructInC {
    let data: (UInt8, UInt8, UInt8)
}
func someOperation(str: StructInC) {
    var s = str
    withUnsafePointer(to: &s) { (sP) -> Void in
        someCFunction(sP)
    }
}
```

This works fine in debug build, but in a release build (swift optimisation enabled, but *not* C library optimisation), when calling `someCFunction`, the data contained in the struct gets corrupted (value of memory inside `someCFunction` is not the same as passed to `someOperation`) when Swift optimisation is enabled (release build) but it works fine in debug build. Is this code valid?

Adding a `print` to log the value of `s` or `str` in `someOperation` prevents this memory corruption occurring, which suggests `str` is being released before `someCFunction` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been confirmed as a [Swift compiler bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-12427).

To workaround this issue you can use [`withExtendedLifetime`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541033-withextendedlifetime):

```
struct StructInC {
    let data: (UInt8, UInt8, UInt8)
}
func someOperation(str: StructInC) {
    var s = str
    withExtendedLifetime(s) {
        withUnsafePointer(to: &s) { (sP) -> Void in
            someCFunction(sP)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create `var s = str` and send a pointer to your func, and never use s after that, the compiler can't seen any reason to keep s around, so it optimizes it away.  Doing anything at all with s will prompt the compiler to keep it around.  I've had trouble like this once before.  I don't know if it's a "feature" or a bug.

I don't know what you mean by "valid", but if the compiler chokes on it, it doesn't matter :)

Comment: What no-op can you do to keep it around? It does seem like a bug because the reference to it is valid for the call of `withUnsafePointer` and the closure is called from that scope

Comment: A workaround is to use [`withExtendedLifetime`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541033-withextendedlifetime) to keep the variable around while the closure executes

Comment: You should put up an answer to your question with that in it.  That is very nice to know.